# ASP.NET MVC3 sample project removing home folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using the ASP.NET MVC3 sample project and would like to have new links added to the page that go directly to the root url
So instead of mydomain.com/Home/About it would do mydomain/About.

This page suggests adding a new route. http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2011/04/17/asp-net-mvc-defining-short-urls-for-root-level-pages.aspx

Is there another way? Say I have 5 pages that will be on the root do I have to add a special route for each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumption that you are looking to do a bunch of single path requests/respones, and not just redirect home controller actions, then this is an option.

The link you provide is *one* way to do that.  The other is to create 5 controllers using the default route.  I'm not sure if I would suggest either is better (due to a lack of what your 5 paths actually are), but they both produce the same out come.  If your default route looks like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
          id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

It's basically stating that the default controller is *home* and the default action is *index*. These values are not mutually inclusive, meaning that neither required the other in order to be a default value.

Thus you could do:

*website.com/about* with

```
public AboutController
{
  public ActionResult index()
  {
    return this.View();
  }
}
```

and/or *website.com/people* with

```
public PeopleController
{
  public ActionResult index()
  {
    return this.View();
  }
}
```

Comment: With the PeopleController example this would mean each root page would have to have its own folder and index.aspx in it. Did I get that right?

When I said is there a better way I ware referring to changing the default route. So just removing the home and bringing everything up one level. I still have subpages like mydomain.com/Products and  mydomain.com/Products/Product1

Comment: My example does not in any way, prevent you from creating other controllers that have more actions beyond the default action in the default route, so `/Products` and `/Products/Product` are still available.

Comment: Yes I wasn't suggesting that your method wouldn't work I was just giving a clarification of my situation. But I get the feeling adding a new rout for the root pages will be cleaner because I won't need a folder for each one. Thanks for taking the time to answer.